# Does Firefox handle window.onpopstate differently than Chrome and Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, html5-history

I've been trying to get a single page application working on Chrome, Safari and Firefox but Firefox doesn't seem to be executing the window.onpopstate at all.

```
window.onpopstate = function() {
    fullpath = location.pathname;
    console.log(fullpath);
}
```

I have .htaccess routing all requests back to index.html so when the the client makes a request, the browser stores the url as a javascript variable and passes it through the js in index.html

When run in firefox, the variable isn't passed to the index.html page. Anyone have a solution or any suggestions for how to look deeper into this issue?

Comment: When does it not fire? On page load or when the user navigates?

Comment: on page load. Variable never gets loaded.

Comment: so set the variable on page load with the current url

Comment: That seemed to solve my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the Firefox `popstate` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/popstate):

> Browsers tend to handle the popstate event differently on page load.
>   Chrome and Safari always emit a popstate event on page load, but
>   Firefox doesn't.

As epascarello says in his comment, initialize your variables in the `load` event and everything should work in Chrome/Safari and Firefox.

Comment: and I'm guessing a good call would be to have a hashtag fallback for IE?

Comment: @Emanegux If you have enough IE users to make it worth your while, then yes.  Note that [IE10 has support](http://caniuse.com/history).

Comment: FireFox, IE10, etc. are exhibiting the HTML5 standards-compliant behavior.  Up-vote https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=63040 to push Google to fix Chrome.