# Popstate event doesn't work in Firefox anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I'm trying to handle action on popstate event (browser's back button) and it's working perfectly in Chrome, but not in Firefox. Example:

```
$(window).on('popstate', function () {
    console.log('poped');
});
```

If I click back button in Chrome event is triggered, but same action in Firefox doesn't work. `window.onpopstate` doesn't work too. Any solutions? Why is this happening?

Comment: You might want to look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16909195/557748

Comment: Thanks for link, but I read this before. They're saying that popstate event doesn't fire on load in Firefox and that's ok. I want to trigger this event on browser back button and it should work.